# Css Div won't stay inside parent Div

Tags: css, html

I have a div that is 1000px wide. Inside that div is another div that is 4000px wide.
The code looks like this

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39TRK/)

**HTML**

```
 <div id="parent_div">
       <div id="child_div">
       </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent_div{
 position:relative;
 height:500px;
 width:1000px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#child_div{
 position:relative;
 height:500px;
 width:4000px;
}
```

Now this code works in Chrome and Safari, it looks like this in Chrome in Safari
[image]
Black box is Parent Div - Red box is Child Div

This is how I would expect the code to work, but in FireFox the code looks like this
[image]

The child div is pushed out of its Parent. Why does it do this? How can I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Works for me in firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/39TRK/

Comment: You're right. I must have done something else wrong. This code is solid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "position:absolute" instead of relative in child div

Answer (score 0):

just remove overflow : hidden;

```
#parent_div{
 position:relative;
 height:500px;
 width:1000px;
}
```